# App crashes after login or signup, but works after I swipe to quit and reopen

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

The title is kind of lengthy and may be a bit convoluted, but I'll try to break it down. My app is built with Swift and uses Parse as the backend. Upon a successful signup or login, the app opens to the main screen and everything is working. I go to profile, and all of the users signup information is there. I go to the camera, and can take a photo, but when I try to post the photo and send it to Parse, the app crashes. If I exit the app and swipe quit it, then reopen it with the cached user already logged in, everything works perfectly. I can take photos, post them, view them, and there are no issues. My problem only appears when I'm signing up for the first time or logging in. I would post code, but I have no idea what to post, if anyone can give me some assistance I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

**EDIT**

My Apologies for the ambiguity of my first question....I finally have an error message that states: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'....not sure what to make of it, but if someone could help I'd be very grateful.

**Code**

Here is the code of the method that I believe is causing the crash.

```
@IBAction func postPhoto(sender: AnyObject)
{
    var fileData:NSData
    var fileName:NSString
    var fileType:NSString

    if image != nil
    {
        fileData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation((image), 0.7)
        fileName = "image.png"
        fileType = "image"
    }
    else
    {
        fileData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(videoFilePath) as NSData
        fileName = "video.mov"
        fileType = "video"
    }

    let file = PFFile(name: fileName, data: fileData)

    var content = PFObject(className: "Content")
    content["sender"] = self.currentUser
    content["senderObjectId"] = self.currentUser?.objectId
    content["senderUsername"] = self.currentUser?["displayUsername"]
    content["senderProfilePic"] = self.currentUser?["profilePic"]
    content["file"] = file
    content["recipients"] = self.photoRecipients
    content["caption"] = self.photoCaption.text
    content.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success:Bool!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if success != nil
        {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
            self.reset()
        }
        else
        {
            var alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "There is a poor network connection, please try again", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        }
    }
}
```

**Answer**

The problem was in my viewDidLoad. I was checking for currentUser and then setting photoRecipients based off of that. There is no currentUser when the view controller is initially called, the login screen is shown. Because of that photoRecipients is never set, and when the main view controller shows up again, viewDidLoad has already been called and photoRecipients is still set to nil.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    if currentUser != nil
    {   
        var query = PFUser.query()
        query.orderByAscending("username")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (NSArray objects, NSError error) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                for user in objects
                {
                    self.contentRecipients.append(user.objectId)
                }
            }
        })
        currentUserObjectId = currentUser?.objectId
        currentUserDisplayUsername = currentUser?["displayUsername"] as? NSString
    }
    else
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showLogin", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Forget that it works okay after the crash.  Focus on the crash.  The way to post a question about it is to add an exception breakpoint, and post the code around where the crash occurs.  And post every bit of the console output on the crash.

Comment: My apologies for the ambiguity of my post...I have added an exception breakpoint like you said and run my code. It breaks on some random line of code in my thread that I don't understand. When I continue past the breakpoint I finally get to an error message that reads: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'

Comment: @user3353890, post the code or no one can help you.

Comment: @WMios I have posted the code that I believe is causing the issue above. Thanks for taking a look at my problem.

Comment: @user3353890, it would appear that self.user, self.photoRecipients, and/or self.photoCaption.text is/are nil.

Comment: @WMios I finally figured out the issue. As you predicted, my self.photoRecipients object was nil upon login or signup. This is because I set photoRecipients in viewDidLoad. I've posted the code above and you can probably see the problem. If there is no currentUser, the login screen is shown. The problem was that once I got back to my main app screen, viewDidLoad had already been called and photoRecipients was never being set. Thanks for your help and for working with me, I appreciate it!

Comment: @user3353890, see my answer that I posted and please select it as the correct answer.

Comment: more than happy to...thanks again for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that self.user, self.photoRecipients, and/or self.photoCaption.text is/are nil. You need to make sure none are nil and it should work.

Comment: sorry it took me so long to figure out

Comment: @user3353890, don't worry it's fine.